# Exclude class from "Unnecessarily qualified inner class access" inspection

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, lint, code-inspection

I want to keep the `Unnecessarily qualified inner class access` enabled but when programming in Android I prefer to ignore a particular class (`R` class) from this rule.

---

In the preferences there is no edit option. My ideas to solve this are:

1. Copy the lint inspection and custom edit it to exclude that class
2. Create a similar lint from scratch that does the same as the
   warning but excludes that class

---

I would input over how to edit if possible the existing lint or if I can access somehow the lint (plugin,  Android studio?) or any other idea/solution to solve the above.